# Implementing Glide in a Custom Adapter used for Gridview of items

Tags: java, android, android-glide, custom-adapter

I am new to android programming and am unable to correctly use the syntax of glide (i.e: with(context) and load protocols) in the custom adapter. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance

Tried changing context to view1 and creating a new context

```
String[] HelmetNames = {"Helmet 1","Helmet 2","Helmet 3","Helmet 4","Helmet 5","Helmet 6"};
        int[] HelmetImages = {R.drawable.a7021906,R.drawable.a7021038,R.drawable.a2111976,R.drawable.a7751025,R.drawable.a3739,R.drawable.a2661082};
       String[] HelmetDetails={"4-point ratchet suspension allows wearer to customize height and fit\n • Suspension sits lower on head to reduce pressure and increase security\n • Short brim enhances better upward visibility\n • Slots allow for attachment of safety accessories\n\n\n\nhttps://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/828564O/3m-head-protection-hard-hats-101-technical-bulletin.pdf","4-point ratchet suspension allows wearer to customize height and fit\n • Suspension sits lower on head to reduce pressure and increase security\n • Short brim enhances better upward visibility\n • Slots allow for attachment of safety accessories\n\n\n\nhttps://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/828564O/3m-head-protection-hard-hats-101-technical-bulletin.pdf","4-point ratchet suspension allows wearer to customize height and fit\n • Suspension sits lower on head to reduce pressure and increase security\n • Short brim enhances better upward visibility\n • Slots allow for attachment of safety accessories\n\n\n\nhttps://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/828564O/3m-head-protection-hard-hats-101-technical-bulletin.pdf","4-point ratchet suspension allows wearer to customize height and fit\n • Suspension sits lower on head to reduce pressure and increase security\n • Short brim enhances better upward visibility\n • Slots allow for attachment of safety accessories\n\n\n\nhttps://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/828564O/3m-head-protection-hard-hats-101-technical-bulletin.pdf","4-point ratchet suspension allows wearer to customize height and fit\n • Suspension sits lower on head to reduce pressure and increase security\n • Short brim enhances better upward visibility\n • Slots allow for attachment of safety accessories\n\n\n\nhttps://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/828564O/3m-head-protection-hard-hats-101-technical-bulletin.pdf","4-point ratchet suspension allows wearer to customize height and fit\n • Suspension sits lower on head to reduce pressure and increase security\n • Short brim enhances better upward visibility\n • Slots allow for attachment of safety accessories\n\n\n\nhttps://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/828564O/3m-head-protection-hard-hats-101-technical-bulletin.pdf"};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_headgrid);

            //finding listview
            gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridview);

            CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
            gridView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),HelmetNames[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HeadGridItemActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name1",HelmetNames[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("image1",HelmetImages[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("details1",HelmetDetails[i]);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });


        }

        private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return HelmetImages.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int i) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int i) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_datahead,null);
                //getting view in row_data
                TextView name = view1.findViewById(R.id.helmetname);
                ImageView image = view1.findViewById(R.id.helmetimages);
                Glide.with(context)
                     .load(HelmetImages[i])
                     .into(image);

                name.setText(HelmetNames[i]);
               // image.setImageResource(HelmetImages[i]);
                return view1;



            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Glide? Glide is not required if you don't open an image URL.

You can just use this

```
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageView.setImageDrawable(res);
```

You can use Glide if you need loading photo from URL, cropping a photo, transition etc.

```
Glide.with(yourContext)
    .load(url)
    .apply(cropOptions)
    .transition(withCrossFade())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Ohh I see, The images I am using are extremely large. When using them in a gridview, it causes the actiivity to fail. I checked a guide online which said glide can auto resize them

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what error is showing to you, but take a look how to make a custom adapter and load images using `Glide` here [custom listView](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-listadapter-listview-gridview)

And as @Beyazid mentioned in his answer, you don't need to use Glide if you are displaying some local images.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to use large images in the gridview. The reason I am using large images is because they are subsequently passed to the next activities and are used as a catalog. It is not possible for me to reduce the size of 100s of images for the gridview imageviews. I assumed glide was used for auto resizing

Comment: You can reduce images resolution using Glide too. If you need any further question I'll be happy to help you.